# Is there another way to ensure NancyFx SSL for all modules?

Tags: c#, security, nancy

I would like to know the correct way of enforcing SSL for all calls to my Nancy API. My current (C#) implementation is:

```
public abstract class NancyHttpsModule : NancyModule
{
    public NancyHttpsModule(string baseUrl) : base(baseUrl)
    {
        this.RequiresHttps();
    }       
}
```

This seems to work with 403 Forbidden on the Non-SSL port.

Is there a better way to do this? (Without using IIS redirects like [this article](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2014/08/permament-redirect-to-https-with-iis/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a BeforeRequestHook to ispect and issue a redirect. Create a startup task in your project, you do not need to hook it, Nancy will pick it up. (pseudo code follows):

```
public class AlwaysUseHttps : IApplicationStartUp
{
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToSTartOfPiepline(RedirectIfNotHttps);
    }

    private static Response RedirectIfNotHttps(NancyContext context)
    {
       //return null if it is already https
       //else, do a redirect as shown here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Security/ModuleSecurity.cs
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is of use to anyone else - final implementation: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wiltshih/fc5c7ec8b44dcabcf3bf)